# express-generator-typescript generated bundle is not able to run debugger successfully

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio, npm

I am generating a type script project using express-generator-typescript(1.4.2) . Now I want to apply visual studio debugger to this newly created bundle but am not able to do it . I am getting error .

```
/usr/bin/node --inspect-brk=15587 dist/src/Server.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:15587/552eb586-a9ba-49ec-8fae-2a8834625bd4
Debugger attached.
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@daos'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pankaj/express-gen-ts/dist/src/routes/Users.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

@daos is a default package . I am not changing anything in the newly created folder .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

Make you include `"-r", "tsconfig-paths/register",` in your vs-code launch.json file.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Dev Env",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "-r", "ts-node/register",
            "-r", "tsconfig-paths/register",
        ],
        "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder:PhotonSuite}/src/index.ts"
        ],
        "protocol": "inspector"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to use aliases without importing module. Try requiring 'module-alias/register' in your starting file.